# Getting SQL query results in MS Access but not in VBScript

Tags: sql, vbscript, ms-access-2007

When I perform a SQL Query through MS Access I get results returned but if I perform the same query in VBScript my RecordCount is -1. I can't tell if this is a connection error.  I'm not getting any but it's clear that the SQL does return results in Access. I'm getting 0 hits in the below connect code.

```
sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM i2cner WHERE Authors Like 'Ish*';"
dim conn
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
conn.Open "d:/inetpub/ga/sarina/i2cner/contacts2000.mdb"
set r = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
if r.state = 1 then r.close
r.Open sqlquery, conn
hits = r.RecordCount
session("hits") = hits
set session("r") = r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r.CursorLocation = 3 'adUseClient. Thanks @HansUp
```

Add the above line before using `r.Open`.
The `CursorLocation` is `adUseServer`. As a result, records are fetched as you progress (similar to .net datareader). Changing it to `adUseClient` will bring all records on the client side, which will give correct `RecordCount`.

EDIT: Also, it isn't meaningful to store recordset in session. And, you should close the connection once you are done using it -

`conn.Close`
`set conn = Nothing`

What is the need to store recordset in session?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the number of record counts then you can give

```
sqlquery = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM i2cner WHERE Authors LIKE 'Ish%'"
```

Note that there is no `;` in the SQL string.
When you have to retrieve the count, you can just have

```
hits = r.fields("cnt")
```

OR

```
hits = r("cnt")
```

`Recordcount` is sometimes deceptive, so I don't use it much. I use the above approach every time.

Comment: Yes. Right. I didn't know this about MS Access. Editing the answer accordingly.